# GDB doesn't see sources

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a following problem. I runned a programm which has created several threads.
Gdb outputs the following threads:

```
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  3    LWP 23941         0x00007f5fc327c2d4 in ?? ()
  2    LWP 22925         0x00007f5fc327e420 in ?? ()
* 1    LWP 23934         0x00007f5fc2779475 in ?? ()
```

Backtrace of the 2nd thread looks as follows:

```
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (LWP 22925)]
#0  0x00007f5fc327e420 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5fc327e420 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f5fb406f300 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000439021 in AaSemWait (semPtr=0x7f5fb406f300) at ../bm/testing/unit/src/ccs/AaSem.cpp:97
#3  0x00000000004197d5 in bm_semaphore_base::wait (this=0x7fff75b01db8) at /home/michaelfrysztacki/bm_local_build2/BTS_SC_BM/bm/interface/framework/bm_semaphore.h:174
#4  0x0000000000500e1c in radio::thread_synchroniser::wait (this=0x7fff75b01c00) at /home/michaelfrysztacki/bm_local_build2/BTS_SC_BM/bm/radio/testing/stubs/radio_module_receiver.h:107
#5  0x00000000005034a5 in radio::mt_radio_service::send_messages (this=0x7f5fb406d140) at ../bm/radio/testing/unit/mt_radio_service.cpp:236
#6  0x0000000000503010 in radio::mt_radio_service::simulate_radio_modules (this=0x7f5fb406d140, set_timeoff_test=false) at ../bm/radio/testing/unit/mt_radio_service.cpp:189
#7  0x00000000004fde77 in radio::mt_radio_service_module_test_sending_message_and_receive_from_radio_service_Test::TestBody (this=0x7f5fb406d140) at ../bm/radio/testing/unit/mt_radio_service.cpp:347
#8  0x000000000069cab1 in void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) ()
....
```

This backtrace satisfies me because I know where the programm stopped.
I am confused about the 1st backtrace:

```
(gdb) thread 1
[Switching to thread 1 (LWP 23934)]
#0  0x00007f5fc2779475 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5fc2779475 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f5fc277c675 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Perhaps this thread runned into a shared library where I don't have debug symbols and sources and I am ok with it. I want to know where from my programm invoked the shared library method. I cannot determine it with this backtrace. I can download some shared libraries with debuging symbols but how can I know which shared library entered my thread ? Or maybe this is the entry point of starting thread using pthread ? Why is this backtrace so poor ? Lastly I am not entirely sure if this is a shared library how can I get it ?

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
                                        No          /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
                                        No          /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0
                                        No          /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so.8
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
                                        No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                                        No          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                                        No          /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

the 'info sharedlibrary' command lists the shared libraries where I have no debugging symbols. How can I get the library e.g.  /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 with debuging symbols ( and sources ) ?

Comment: Have you built your application with debug information? Linked with debug-libraries (if available)? Then that's all you can do. If the debugger stops on code without any debug information, it's most likely in a library without information, and all you can do is walk `up` the call stack to your code (where the problem most likely is anyway).

Comment: On my ubuntu the debug pthread libraries  are found in `/usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnulibpthread-2.11.1.so`, make sure you are using similar ones

Comment: The backtrace of second thread already show us, that my application was built with debugging symbols. I've added some information about missing shared libraries debug symbols above in my first post.

Comment: One possibility is that it (meaning your code :) ) has corrupted the stack trace of another thread. May be I would suspect my code first, unless I am using very un-guaranteed 3rd part library.

Answer (score 1):

Your `info shared` output shows that GDB did not load symbols for *any* shared library.

The most likely cause: you have `set auto-solib-add off` somewhere in your `~/.gdbinit` file.

You should be able to fix this with either

- `(gdb) shared .`  -- force GDB to read all shared libraries, or
- just take out the `set auto-solib-add off` from wherever it's coming from.